# How can I unify the routing Urls for views rendered inside an iframe

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

We are using an Iframe inside our main Index page. I wrote a controller that allows one to request resources (Images, Js, Css etc..) much like you would with a handler.

```
@Html.Css("Ico16", "Add")
//Converts to this
<link src="Style?Key=ico16&File=add" type="text/css" />
```

The route to request an Image will also appear the same as such:

```
<img src="Image?Key=ico16&File=add" />
```

However this next route only works on Views displayed within the Iframe.

```
<link src="Default/Style?Key=Ico16&File=Add" type="text/css" />
```

And finally, the water becomes a little more murky bc although css only requests the Action as shown above ... if I am inside a external javascript file, I must add the controller name to the route again like so:

```
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
     $('#SomeDiv').append('<img src="Default/Image?Key=ico16&File=add"></img>');
 })
```

**How can I unify these routes so that they all consistent?** I frankly don't care which way it is written so long as it is not different for different areas of content.

The routes:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "PlatformIFrame",
        "{controller}/{action}/{key}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", key = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Platform",
        "{action}/{key}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", key = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
```

The controller:

```
public class DefaultController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Style(string key, string file)
    {
    }

    public ActionResult Script(string key, string file)
    {
    }

    public ActionResult Image(string key, string file)
    {
    }  
 }
```

Comment: Why aren't you linking directly to /content for styles, scripts and images?

Comment: @Cymen Two very valid reasons: First, I have an internal caching process, caching depends on the ability to intercept requests for resources. How would you easily accommodate that just placing resources directly?

The second reason is for maintainability's sake. What if we decide to relocate all of our resources? Do you want to be the guy that has to update all the URLs to the resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've thought about this a bit and I think the answer may be very simple.

Use only this route:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Platform",
        "{action}/{key}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", key = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
```

Use only this style (note the leading "/") for your URLs:

```
<link src="/Style?Key=Ico16&File=Add" type="text/css" />
```

If you want to get rid of this problem completely, you could also do this:

```
<link src="<%: Url.Action("Style", "Default", new { key = "Ico16", file = "Add" }) %>" type="text/css" />
```

If you choose the above option, you should leave the route which includes the controller name in the URL in and remove the one without the controller name.